# Удаленное использование Graphhopper сервера

Tags: сеть

Я установил Graphhopper на свой компьютер. Он работает на localhost:8989, но когда я обращаюсь с другого компьютера на IP:8989, то он не работает.

Comment: На *Stack Overflow **на русском*** вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке.

Comment: Порт открыт? IP машины внешний или внутренний? Если внешний, то нужно проброс делать.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в конфиге параметр `bindHost`. Вероятно, у вас `bindHost: localhost`. Попробуйте удалить эту строчку.